# How to use a variable created in class1, in another class?

Tags: java, class, variables, bluej

I’m trying to create a password programme that lets the user create an account and then be able to change username, password and access the account.

This is where I’m at so far:

class 2

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class mainPage extends JFrame {
    create_account crAcc = new create_account();
    change_username chU = new change_username();
    change_password chPW = new change_password();
    sign_in signIn = new sign_in();

    private JButton create_account, change_username, change_password, signIn_button;

    public mainPage(){
        super("Password Programme"); 

        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (400, 100));
        setLayout (null);

        create_account = new JButton("Create an Account");
        add(create_account);

        change_username = new JButton("Change Username");
        add(change_username);

        change_password = new JButton("Change Password");
        add(change_password);

        signIn_button = new JButton("Sign in and Access Files");
        add(signIn_button);


        create_account.setBounds (10, 20, 150, 20);
        change_username.setBounds (10, 50, 150, 20);
        change_password.setBounds (10, 80, 150, 20);
        signIn_button.setBounds (10, 110, 200, 20);

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        create_account.addActionListener(handler);
        change_username.addActionListener(handler);
        change_password.addActionListener(handler);
        signIn_button.addActionListener(handler);
    }

    private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            if(event.getSource()==create_account) {
                crAcc.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
                crAcc.setSize(300,200); 
                crAcc.setVisible(true);
            }
            if(event.getSource()==change_username) {
                chU.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
                chU.setSize(300,200); 
                chU.setVisible(true);
            }
            if(event.getSource()==change_password) {
                chPW.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                chPW.setSize(300,200); 
                chPW.setVisible(true);
            }
            if(event.getSource()==signIn_button) {
                signIn.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                signIn.setSize(300,200); 
                signIn.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

class 3

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class create_account extends JFrame{
    private String u1, pw1;
    private JLabel cU1, cpw1, statusBar;

    public JTextField create_u1; 
    public JPasswordField create_pw1;
    private JButton change;

    change_username objOfClass4 = new change_username();

    public create_account() {
        super("Create Account"); 
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (400, 85));
        setLayout (null);

        statusBar = new JLabel("Create a username");
        add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);        
        statusBar.setBounds(20, 110, 250, 30); 

        cU1 = new JLabel("Username");
        cpw1 = new JLabel("Password");
        create_u1 = new JTextField(10);
        create_pw1 = new JPasswordField(10);

        cU1.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 30); 
        create_u1.setBounds(100, 10, 100, 30); 
        cpw1.setBounds(10, 50, 150, 30); 
        create_pw1.setBounds(100, 50, 100, 30); 

        add(create_u1);
        add(cU1);

        create_u1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username saved. Now create a password");

                    statusBar.setText("Create a password");

                    add(cpw1);
                    add(create_pw1);

                    cpw1.repaint();
                    create_pw1.repaint();

                    create_pw1.requestFocus();                   

                    objOfClass4.setUserName(create_u1.getText());
                }
            }
        );

        create_pw1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password saved");

                    statusBar.setText("Account created. Return to main programme");                    

                    statusBar.requestFocus();

                }
            }
        );

    }

}
```

class 4

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class change_username extends JFrame {

    private JLabel uT1, pwT, uCh, statusBar;
    private JTextField username_input, username_change;
    private JPasswordField password_input;   

    private String userName, passWord;


    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    } 

    public void setUserName(String givenUserName) {
        this.userName = givenUserName;
    }

    public change_username() {
        super("Change Username"); 
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (400, 85));
        setLayout (null);

        statusBar = new JLabel("Enter your username");
        add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        statusBar.setBounds(20, 130, 250, 30); 

        uT1 = new JLabel("Username");
        username_input = new JTextField(10);

        pwT = new JLabel("Password");
        password_input = new JPasswordField(10); 

        uCh = new JLabel("New Username");
        username_change = new JTextField(10);

        uT1.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 30); 
        username_input.setBounds(100, 10, 100, 30); 
        pwT.setBounds(10, 50, 150, 30); 
        password_input.setBounds(100, 50, 100, 30);        
        uCh.setBounds(10, 90, 150, 30); 
        username_change.setBounds(100, 90, 100, 30); 

        add(uT1);
        add(username_input);

        username_input.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    statusBar.setText("Enter your password");

                    add(pwT);
                    add(password_input);

                    pwT.repaint();
                    password_input.repaint();

                    password_input.requestFocus();

                    System.out.println(getUserName());

                }
            }
        );       
    }

}
```

I want to access the username that the user entered in the JTextField in class 3, from class 4.

Before doing everything else, I want to print out the username that they entered when they created the account using println(). I've tried multiple ways of doing this, including getters, but none have worked and I'm stuck.

Can someone provide me the exact code that I need that lets me print out the username that they created in the 'create_username' class?
I think I can manage to create the rest of the programme once I achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: If you are aware of the naming conventions in Java, why do you choose to ignore them? It makes reading your code, aka helping you, much more difficult

Comment: Please reduce the code and be very specific about describing the problem, read the [**SSCCE**](http://sscce.org/) for better understanding how to ask a question.

Comment: What I meant was that I was aware that you guys didn't like people not using them. I Didn't use them as I don't know what they are yet and is something that I am planning to learn later.

Comment: i suggest learning it from the beginning ;-)

Comment: @user2587777 It is better to learn [coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) earlier than later as later it will be more difficult to change yourself. And as sunrize920 mentioned it is easier for us to help you.

Comment: You shouldn't remove class 2, or we cannot see the dependency of class 3 & 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two private instance variable

```
public class change_username extends JFrame {

    private JLabel uT1, pwT, uCh, statusBar;
    private JTextField username_input, username_change;
    private JPasswordField password_input;

    // ADD IT HERE **************************************
    private String userName, passWord;

    public String getUserName(){
        return this.userName;
    } 

    public void setUserName(String givenUserName){
        this.userName = givenUserName;
    }

    // **************************************


    public change_username() {
        super("Change Username"); 
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (400, 85));
        setLayout (null);

    // YOUR CODE HERE


// CLASS 3
public class create_account extends JFrame{
    private String u1, pw1;
    class4 objClass4 = new class4();
    u1 = objClass4.getUserName();

    // YOUR code here.......
```

Repeat the same for password, and you should be good. Also, when the Listener is activated use the object of the class to set the userName and the Password. Hope you know, on how to move forward from here.

Comment: I prefer the (deleted) class 2, though.

Comment: @ JNL:  where do I place those?

Comment: @johnchen902 You can create the object of class 4 in class 2 and access it from there via the accessor methods.

Comment: Right i included those in class 4. How does this let class 4 use the variable in class 3 without anything that points to them?

Comment: Are all the classes in the same package? Create an object of class 4 in class 3. Class3{ class4 objOfClass4 = new class4(); }

Comment: Thanks. Yes they are. Trying some things now, will get back to you

Comment: @johnchen902 Am glad the answer was helpful. I would appreciate if you could vote up or accept the answer.

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Comment: I'm sure what you provided is correct but I'm not sure I'm using it correctly. If you want to help me further, I've updated class 3 and 4 above. When the 'println' gets called, it prints 'null'. Thanks. Need to go now, so I'll reply when I get back.

Comment: I would recommend use the debugger. Also see if the text you are getting is correct? String tempText = cu1.getText(); Print it and see if its correct?

Comment: inserted String tempText = cu1.getText(); and it prints correctly. Don't know how to use the debugger yet

Comment: Very Good. So you know, that the data is being extracted correctly. Now you just need to set it in class 4 and print it from there and see if the data is passed properly.

Comment: I inserted: System.out.println(getUserName()); into the class4 method setUserName and it prints correctly from there too. The problem must be from the ActionListener I guess

Comment: You have learned one way of debugging. The other way would be to use the debugger tool. Just google or youtube for some sessions, and you will be good.