# Using a variable from another class in an Action Listener outputs 'null'

Tags: java, swing, variables, null, actionlistener

This is another problem that has come up after having solved my earlier question here:

[How to use a variable created in class1, in another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679750/how-to-use-a-variable-created-in-class1-in-another-class)

The answer to the question above allows me to use a variable created in class 3 to be printed by calling a method in class 4, from class 4.

However, when I try to print that variable as part of an action listener, it prints out 'null' instead of whatever the user inputs in the JTexfield create_u1 (in class 3).

Updated for sajjadG: please try it yourself

class 1

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class class1 extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        mainPage MP = new mainPage();
        MP.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MP.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        MP.setSize(300,200);
        MP.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

class 2

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class mainPage extends JFrame {
    create_account crAcc = new create_account();
    change_username chU = new change_username();
    change_password chPW = new change_password();
    sign_in signIn = new sign_in();

    private JButton create_account, change_username, change_password, signIn_button;

    public mainPage(){
        super("Password Programme"); 

        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (400, 100));
        setLayout (null);

        create_account = new JButton("Create an Account");
        add(create_account);

        change_username = new JButton("Change Username");
        add(change_username);

        change_password = new JButton("Change Password");
        add(change_password);

        signIn_button = new JButton("Sign in and Access Files");
        add(signIn_button);

        create_account.setBounds (10, 20, 150, 20);
        change_username.setBounds (10, 50, 150, 20);
        change_password.setBounds (10, 80, 150, 20);
        signIn_button.setBounds (10, 110, 200, 20);

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        create_account.addActionListener(handler);
        change_username.addActionListener(handler);
        change_password.addActionListener(handler);
        signIn_button.addActionListener(handler);
    }

    private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            if(event.getSource()==create_account) {
                crAcc.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
                crAcc.setSize(300,200); 
                crAcc.setVisible(true);
            }
            if(event.getSource()==change_username) {
                chU.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
                chU.setSize(300,200); 
                chU.setVisible(true);
            }
            if(event.getSource()==change_password) {
                chPW.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
                chPW.setSize(300,200); 
                chPW.setVisible(true);
            }
            if(event.getSource()==signIn_button) {
                signIn.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                signIn.setSize(300,200); 
                signIn.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

class 3

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class create_account extends JFrame{
    private String u1, pw1;
    private JLabel cU1, cpw1, statusBar;

    public JTextField create_u1; 
    public JPasswordField create_pw1;
    private JButton change;

    public String userName3, passWord3;    

    public void checkUserName(String u, String pw) {

        System.out.println(u);          ///// this prints it out correctly
        System.out.println(pw); 

        if (create_u1.getText()==u){
            System.out.println("correct");
        }else {                       /// it tests incorrect even though i inputted same thing
            System.out.println("incorrect");
            System.out.println(create_u1.getText());
            System.out.println(userName3);       /// prints out null            }
    }

    public create_account() {
        super("Create Account"); 
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (400, 85));
        setLayout (null);

        statusBar = new JLabel("Create a username");
        add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);        
        statusBar.setBounds(20, 110, 250, 30); 

        cU1 = new JLabel("Username");
        cpw1 = new JLabel("Password");
        create_u1 = new JTextField(10);
        create_pw1 = new JPasswordField(10);

        cU1.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 30); 
        create_u1.setBounds(100, 10, 100, 30); 
        cpw1.setBounds(10, 50, 150, 30); 
        create_pw1.setBounds(100, 50, 100, 30); 

        add(create_u1);
        add(cU1);

        create_u1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username saved. Now create a password");

                    statusBar.setText("Create a password");

                    add(cpw1);
                    add(create_pw1);

                    cpw1.repaint();
                    create_pw1.repaint();

                    create_pw1.requestFocus();                   

                }
            }
        );

        create_pw1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password saved");

                    statusBar.setText("Account created. Return to main programme");                    

                    statusBar.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        );
    }

}
```

class 4

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class change_username extends JFrame {

    private JLabel uT1, pwT, uCh, statusBar;
    private JTextField username_input, username_change;
    private JPasswordField password_input;   

    create_account objOfClass3 = new create_account();

    public void checkUserName() {
        objOfClass3.checkUserName(username_input.getText(), password_input.getText());
    }

    public change_username() {
        super("Change Username"); 
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (400, 85));
        setLayout (null);

        statusBar = new JLabel("Enter your username");
        add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        statusBar.setBounds(20, 130, 250, 30); 

        uT1 = new JLabel("Username");
        username_input = new JTextField(10);

        pwT = new JLabel("Password");
        password_input = new JPasswordField(10); 

        uCh = new JLabel("New Username");
        username_change = new JTextField(10);

        uT1.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 30); 
        username_input.setBounds(100, 10, 100, 30); 
        pwT.setBounds(10, 50, 150, 30); 
        password_input.setBounds(100, 50, 100, 30);        
        uCh.setBounds(10, 90, 150, 30); 
        username_change.setBounds(100, 90, 100, 30); 

        add(uT1);
        add(username_input);

        username_input.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    statusBar.setText("Enter your password");

                    add(pwT);
                    add(password_input);

                    pwT.repaint();
                    password_input.repaint();

                    password_input.requestFocus();

                }
            }
        );        

        password_input.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    statusBar.setText("Enter your new username");

                    add(uCh);
                    add(username_change);

                    uCh.repaint();
                    username_change.repaint();

                    username_change.requestFocus();

                    checkUserName();
                }
            }
        );

        username_change.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    statusBar.setText("Username Changed. Return to main programme");

                    username_change.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        );         
    }

}
```

Comment: did you call `setUserName` in some part? consider making a `SSCCE` your post is too big consider that you have problems in 4th class, also you should consider learning java code conventions to let others understand your code easily

Comment: Yes. When I call it in class 3, it works and it prints whatever the user inputs into the JTextField. Problem is when getUserName() is called from a println inside the action listener in class 4, it prints out 'null'

Comment: in class 3 you are calling `JTextField` in class 4 you are calling `getUserName()` that returns an String that you never previous set, thats why you get null

Comment: I think I understand your answer. How may I fix this?

Comment: you have a lot of mistakes in code, so i don't want to make a big answer... but you have to `setUserName` before you call `getUserName`

Comment: Thanks. Haven't I already done setUserName when I call  objOfClass4.setUserName(create_u1.getText()); in class3? Doesn't this save that variable as userName in class 4?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here, you are not setting the value for the text field.
Do something like

```
username_input.setText(userName);
```

Put the above line in setUserName(){}

**OR**

```
public change_username() {
        super("Change Username"); 
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (400, 85));
        setLayout (null);

        statusBar = new JLabel("Enter your username");
        add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        statusBar.setBounds(20, 130, 250, 30); 

        uT1 = new JLabel("Username");
        username_input = new JTextField(10);

        pwT = new JLabel("Password");
        password_input = new JPasswordField(10); 

        uCh = new JLabel("New Username");
        username_change = new JTextField(10);

        uT1.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 30); 
        username_input.setBounds(100, 10, 100, 30); 
        pwT.setBounds(10, 50, 150, 30); 
        password_input.setBounds(100, 50, 100, 30);        
        uCh.setBounds(10, 90, 150, 30); 
        username_change.setBounds(100, 90, 100, 30); 

        add(uT1);
        add(username_input);

        // SET THE TEXT HERE Before the Listener **************************

        username_input.setText(getUserName());

        // *****************************************************************
```

Then your code ahead.....

Comment: No it didn't. Doesn't the setUserName correctly save the variable as userName?

Comment: Change it to username_input.SetText(userName); userName pritns the variable correctly right? Debug it. Put one more println() and see.

Comment: still doesn't fix it unfortunately. creates an error when i try to run it

Comment: Do this. put username_input.setText(userName); in your setUserName() method. I executed it on my machine. Worked fine. Try and let me know

Comment: You basically need to set the username in the text_field as others recommended.

Comment: Still outputs null mate, I appreciate the effort you are putting in.

Comment: I edited the code in my answer. It worked fine on my machine.

Comment: tried it again and it prints null. Think I'm just going to come back to this once I learn more. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are not setting `userName` attribute first. you should set `usernName` first then try `getUserName()`

Try adding below line in your `actionPerformed` method before printing userName

```
setUserName(username_input.getText());
```

here is the corrected and tested code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ChangeUsername extends JFrame {

    private JLabel uT1, pwT, uCh, statusBar;
    private JTextField usernameInput, usernameChange;
    private JPasswordField passwordInput;
    public String userName, passWord;

    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String givenUserName) {
        this.userName = givenUserName;
        System.out.println(getUserName());   /////// this correctly prints the variable
    }

    public ChangeUsername() {
        super("Change Username");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 85));
        setLayout(null);

        statusBar = new JLabel("Enter your username");
        add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        statusBar.setBounds(20, 130, 250, 30);

        uT1 = new JLabel("Username");
        usernameInput = new JTextField(10);

        pwT = new JLabel("Password");
        passwordInput = new JPasswordField(10);

        uCh = new JLabel("New Username");
        usernameChange = new JTextField(10);

        uT1.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 30);
        usernameInput.setBounds(100, 10, 100, 30);
        pwT.setBounds(10, 50, 150, 30);
        passwordInput.setBounds(100, 50, 100, 30);
        uCh.setBounds(10, 90, 150, 30);
        usernameChange.setBounds(100, 90, 100, 30);

        add(uT1);
        add(usernameInput);

        usernameInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                statusBar.setText("Enter your password");
                add(pwT);
                add(passwordInput);

                pwT.repaint();
                passwordInput.repaint();
                passwordInput.requestFocus();

                setUserName(usernameInput.getText());// setting the username
//                statusBar.setText(statusBar.getText() + " " + getUserName());
                System.out.println(getUserName()); ////// this line does not
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        new ChangeUsername().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Also I should mention that you should start using Java naming convention and use meaningful names for your classes, attributes and methods.

- classes start with Upercase letter
- methods and attribute start with lower case
- all of identifiers are camelCase so don't use _ between them. write getUserName instead of get_user_name

Read this [link](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) for more rules on Java naming convention.

And you need to learn more about OOP. So I suggest reading book Thinking in Java. [TIJ third edition](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/%E2%80%8E)  is free and good.

Comment: This saves the userName as whatever the user inputs into the JTextField in class4, I'm trying to print out what he inputs in class3. (This was for your previous answer)

Comment: (for your second suggestion) I want to use the variable, saved in class 3, in class 4.

Comment: @user2587777 you should use `getter` and `setter` of `class3` in order to be able to access its attribute in other classes such as `class4`. but if you are not going to new an instance from another class `class3` you can send `class3` as argument to `class4` constructor.

Comment: OK, ill try to make those now

Comment: @user2587777 I think you wrote the question wrong! where do you want to print your username? in class4 where it is or in another class?

Comment: From class 4, when the user presses enter into 'username_input' JTextField, I want to print whatever the USER INPUTS into the 'create_u1' JTextField in class3.

Comment: @user2587777 Like I mentioned before, you can send `class3` as an argument to `class4` and then use its setUserName method like this `setUserName(jtfUsername().getText());`

Comment: @user2587777 you forgot to add the `sign_in` class but it is not important for now. you need to pass `username` and `password` to your `create_account` class. you can do it by passing parameter. create a constructor like this `create_account(String username, String pass)` and use them in your class. don't forget to instantiate `create_account` class. your question has answered before. and this questions should not be asked here.

Comment: I understand, and I have updated class 3 and 4. When I try to use the variable that was created in class4 and compare it with the variable created in class 3, using an IF statement, it doesn't come out correctly, which would suggest that it is changing it null

Comment: @user2587777 I told you to correct your code with good naming convention. and you should try try try to get it work. and ask a good question not putting all of your code and ask for correcting your code. and you also accepted an answer for this question. it means you got your answer and answering to this question is useless anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have changed the code so that it saves the username and password into a .txt file, so I will be able to read from them instead.

Comment: @user2587777 that's a workaround but you should read more about OOP in Java and try to learn how to pass information between classes.